# How to use duplicated()

Tags: r, duplicates, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a dataset which has customer purchase information. I have tried to create unique id by concatenating device_id(of the customer), store_id, product_id and date (of purchase). I have used the following code for this

```
customer$device_store_product_date <- paste(customer$device, customer$store_id, customer$product_id, customer$date, sep='_')
```

The resultant column is something like this:

```
        device_store_product_date
48c6eec37affa1db_203723_9313962_2016-02-19
eb2c2f00071b97f3_179926_6180944_2016-02-20
d82066a784c9552_180704_9308311_2016-02-20
9766bba65b1ef9ac_204187_9313852_2016-02-20
77d80c1066f5267_180488_9312672_2016-02-20
```

As expected there are still duplicates. To identify them i used duplicated():

```
x1 = customer[duplicated(customer$device_store_product_date),]
```

However, for few of the x1$device_store_product_date only single entries are present. This should not be the case as x1 should consist of repeated values. Let me know where am i going wrong. To select entries corresponding to a particular value of device_store_product_date i have used:

```
filter(x1, x1$device_store_product_date=="14163e6b6ed06890_203723_9313477_2016-02-20")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicated() returns TRUE for any value that has already occurred, so

```
x <-c("a","b","a")
duplicated(x)
```

will return

```
FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

If you want to get all the first occurrence as well, something like this will work

```
duplicated(x)|rev(duplicated(rev(x)))
```

Comment: That solved my problem...thanks. If possible could you please explain duplicated(x)|rev(duplicated(rev(x))). I am have just started learning R.

Comment: The vertical bar means OR and rev() will reverse the order of the vector, so start looking for duplicates from the other end.
The solution by akrun is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicated` function has an argument `fromLast=TRUE` to check for duplicates from the end.  Here, the last element will be FALSE and all other duplicates return TRUE.  By using `|`, we ensure that all the duplicate elements are included.

```
 duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)
```

can be used to get all the duplicate elements